# RIP: Adam West, star of Batman

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Adam West, star of the 1960 [Batman TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)) has [passed away](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/adam-west-dead-batman-star-832264) at the age of 88.

A well-recognised actor who struggled to find regular employment after Batman, West never allowed his shortcomings as an actor (or dancer, see below) to prevent him from finding acting work, enjoying considerable success in later life with recurring roles on Family Guy, and The Fairly OddParents.

His fanbase is numerous and vocal and he will be sorely missed.

[image][image]

Comment: Anyone that is looking at this page should see the tribute for Adam West by Kevin Smith and Ralph Garman. It reminds us why he was a hero.

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino Link?

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino Yes. Link.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAavLplaL0M

Comment: To those voting to close: The consensus (although I don't agree with it) is that RIP posts about SF&F actors are on topic on SF&F Meta, so this post should not be closed as off topic.

Comment: @Blackwood - Close votes? *Down*votes, surely

Comment: I came across the question on the close vote review queue.

Comment: Long live Colonel Dan McReady!